# How to remove multiple versions of python from MacOS Catalina 10.15.4

Tags: python, macos, duplicates

I currently have python versions 2.7, 3.8, and 3.9 on my Mac and it just causes problems in package installing, etc. I do not know how to remove all of them and reinstall python from the beginning in a clean way this time. What should I delete?

Comment: Maybe refer to this post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284824/remove-and-reinstall-python-on-mac-can-i-trust-these-old-references.

Comment: What problems, exactly? Better to learn how to correctly manage multiple Python installations than to indiscriminately remove things.

Answer (score -1):

First, delete the folder `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/` using this command:
`sudo rm -r /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/`

Second, remove everything related to python (`python2.7`, `python3.8`, etc.) in this dir: `/usr/local/bin/`

**NOTE:** You need admin permissions to do this on your computer.

Comment: I *strongly* recommend against deleting anything from `Library`. Don't touch anything that was installed by the OS. (And more generally, don't uninstall things installed by package managers like `brew` manually.)